# How to loop through list then return redirect

Tags: python, django

I am doing a file check by name after files are uploaded but the loop ends after the first file in the loop due to there being a `return redirect` if file exists.

I have tried searching for similar issues to no avail. Likely due to not knowing how to word the question.

```
def check_for_file(self):
    names = ['media/reports/Stylist_Analysis.xls',
             'media/reports/Tips_By_Employee.xls',
             'media/reports/Employee_Hours.xls',
             'media/reports/Employee_Hours (1).xls',
             'media/reports/Employee_Service_Efficiency_SC 8-10.xls',
             'media/reports/SC_Client_Retention_Report.xls']
    for name in names:
        if os.path.isfile(name):
            return redirect('landing')
        else:
            return redirect('blog-home')
```

I would like it to loop over each file path and check if file exists. Once every file is confirmed I would like it to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def check_for_file(self):
    names = ['media/reports/Stylist_Analysis.xls',
             'media/reports/Tips_By_Employee.xls',
             'media/reports/Employee_Hours.xls',
             'media/reports/Employee_Hours (1).xls',
             'media/reports/Employee_Service_Efficiency_SC 8-10.xls',
             'media/reports/SC_Client_Retention_Report.xls']
    for name in names:
        if not os.path.isfile(name):
            return redirect('landing') # <--- redirects here if at least one file is missing

    return redirect('blog-home') # <--- redirects here if all files are present
```

Comment: In my code, it will redirect after checking the first file only if it doesn't exist. If it exists, the loop continues. If this is not what you want, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I apologize! I had not realized your return statement at the bottom was moved over and without an else statement

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. :)